# How to define a function that will convert list into dictionary while also inserting 'None' where there is no value for a key (Python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary, nonetype

Say we have a contact_list like this:

```
[["Joey", 30080],["Miranda"],["Lisa", 30081]]
```

So essentially "Miranda" doesn't have a zipcode, but with the function I want to define, I'd like it to automatically detect that and add "None" into her value slot, like this:

```
{
"Joey": 30080,
"Miranda": None,
"Lisa": 30081
}
```

So far I have this, which just converts the list to a dict:

```
def user_contacts(contact_list):
    dict_contact = dict(contact_list)
    print(dict_contact)
```

Not sure where I go from here, as far as writing in the code to add the None for "Miranda". Currently, I just get an error that says the 1st element ("Miranda") requires two lengths instead of one.

Eventually I want to just a pass any list like the one above in the defined function: user_contacts and, again, be able to get the dictionary above as the output.

```
user_contacts([["Joey", 30080],["Miranda"],["Lisa", 30081]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is what you can do. you can check to see if the `len` of a certain element in your list, meets the expectations (in this case, 2 for name and zipcode). then if it fails the expectations, you can add "none":

```
contacts = [["Joey", 30080], ["Miranda"], ["Lisa", 30081]]
contacts_dict = {}
for c in contacts:
    if len(c) < 2:
        c.append('None')
    contacts_dict.update({c[0]: c[1]})
print(contacts_dict)
```

and the output is:

```
{'Joey': 30080, 'Miranda': 'None', 'Lisa': 30081}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def user_contacts(contact_list):
    dict_contact = dict((ele[0], ele[1] if len(ele) > 1 else None) for ele in 
    contact_list)
    print(dict_contact)
```